# is there any query for create table from the existing table in pentaho

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am using data integration tool Pentaho, I am trying to creates not working a big table from the source of an existing table, but it not working its show some error log my code is like

```
create table table_S as (select * from table_A);
```

any answers??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you for sure :

```
SELECT * INTO table_S FROM table_A WHERE 1=2
```